# mysql select todo tasks as per timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select todo rows from mysql db using current time. Please check mysql query as following...

```
SELECT * FROM todos WHERE status = "pending" AND date(now()) = date(ts) AND hour(now()) = hour(ts) AND minute(now()) = minute(ts) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

It works fine but is there any way to optimize it better and fast?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `explain select ...` and share the result into the question.

Comment: can you try SELECT * FROM todos WHERE status = "pending" AND NOW() = ts ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 . I guess `ts` is your time stamp field name in database......

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes what happens if it runs at 20:00:15, i think it won't select row then by using `NOW() = ts`

Comment: For that better solution will be collecting all data from db table for today's date and than sorting them as per your needs using PHP. This will make it more faster and reliable.

Comment: Also you can use this: SELECT * FROM todos WHERE status = "pending" AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) = ts ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 .  You can define minutes in here.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would make more sense to see when it's later than when the item in the todo list should be done. Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM todos 
WHERE status = "pending" AND 
      now() > ts
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Depending on the type of `ts` you might need to tweak this a bit.

Comment: Timestamp always saves current time. How can a timestamp be greater than current time??

Comment: No, your question should be: How can the current time be greater than a timestamp. The answer is that both are numbers, or should be make into numbers if your time stamp isn't a number.